# I am not able to Ping IPs from my indexed array but works with an associative array

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I am trying to iterate IPs which are read from a csv to an array as a kind of monitoring solution. I have the ips in a indexed array and want to pass the ips to the ping command but its not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
datei=hosts.csv
length=$(cat $datei  | wc -l)

for (( i=1; i<=$length; i++ ))
do
ips[$i]=$(cut -d ';' -f2 $datei | awk 'NR=='$i'')
hosts[$i]=$(cut -d ';' -f1 $datei | awk 'NR=='$i'')
done

servers=( "1.1.1.1" "8.8.4.4" "8.8.8.8" "4.4.4.4")

for i in ${ips[@]} #Here i change the array i want to iterate
do
echo $i
ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Server down"
        else
        echo "Server alive"
        fi
done
```

Interesting is that if I iterate the server array instead of the ips array it works. The ips array seems from data fine if printed.

The output if I use the servers array:

```
1.1.1.1
Server alive
8.8.4.4
Server alive
8.8.8.8
Server alive
4.4.4.4
Server down
```

and if I use the ips array

```
1.1.1.1
: Name or service not known
Server down
8.8.4.4
: Name or service not known
Server down
8.8.8.8
: Name or service not known
Server down
4.4.4.4
: Name or service not known
Server down
```

Output from cat hosts.csv

```
test;1.1.1.1
test;8.8.4.4
test;8.8.8.8
test;4.4.4.4
```

First column is for Hostnames and the second column for the IPs in v4.

I am on Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS

Comment: This is not how to read file content into an array. Also it would really help answering your question; if you published a sample of the `hosts.csv` file.

Comment: Is added. Is a german standard CSV with ; seperator

Comment: readarray ips <<< "$(awk -F\; '{ print $2 }' Hosts.csv)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed multiple issues with your code:

- Reading of `hosts.csv` into arrays.
- Testing the ping result.

`hosts.csv`:

```
one.one.one.one;1.1.1.1
dns.google;8.8.4.4
dns.google;8.8.8.8
invalid.invalid;4.4.4.4
```

Working commented in code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

datei=hosts.csv
# Initialize empty arrays
hosts=()
ips=()

# Iterate reading host and ip in line records using ; as field delimiter
while IFS=\; read -r host ip _; do
  hosts+=("$host") # Add to the hosts array
  ips+=("$ip") # Add to the ips array
done <"$datei" # From this file

# Iterate the index of the ips array
for i in "${!ips[@]}"; do
  # Display currently processed host and ip
  printf 'Pinging host %s with IP %s\n' "${hosts[i]}" "${ips[i]}"

  # Test the result of pinging the IP address
  if ping -nc 1 "${ips[i]}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Server alive"
  else
    echo "Server down"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Excel was making failures with the csv file. It workes if I make the csv manually in Terminal.

Comment: @PaDre1709 probably Excell is using DOS file ending instead of Unix file ending. Instead of streaming your datei directly do it as `done < <(sed 's/^M$//' "$datei")`

Answer (score 0):

You can read into an array from stdin using readarray and so combining this with awk to parse the Host.csv file:

```
readarray -t ips <<< "$(awk -F\; '{ print $2 }' $date1)"
readarray -t hosts <<< "$(awk -F\; '{ print $1 }' $date1)"
```

Comment: Thank you for showing a nice and sleek way for filling a array from a csv. The problem is that I am not able to pass from the array to the ping command.

Comment: Apologies. You need to add -t to remove the trailing newline. This will allow to use the array in a loop with ping as in your example

Comment: Excel was making failures with the csv file. It workes if I make the csv manually in Terminal. Thanks for your help!